# How To Sort ArrayList in Different List

Tags: java, android

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyData {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")
        );

        System.out.println("Size of AyyayList= "+arrayList.size());
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size()/2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" "+(i+1));
        }
    }
}

my Output 
  Size of AyyayList= 8
  0 1
  1 2
  2 3
  3 4

Need Output

 Size of AyyayList= 8
 0 1
 2 3
 4 5
 6 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need :

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size()/2;i++)
{
    System.out.println(2*i+" "+(2*i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the for loop, instead of `i++` write `i = i + 2.`
The problem is, that you only increase i by one

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i+=2){
   System.out.println(i+" "+arrayList.get(i));
}
```